# Two intersecting disks with subspace topology in $\mathbb {R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Take two closed disks as subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ such that they intersect at exactly one point. Let $\Bbb R^2$ have the standard  euclidean topology $\mathcal J_E$ and give the above set the subspace topology.

Is this space: $a)$ path connected or $b)$ connected?

Now I would assume this is path connected, like I can surely define a path from one disk to the other through the point of intersection continuously? The disks themselves are convex so that sorts them individually. And then path connected implies connected.

Apparently I'm supposed to pay attention to the word continuous...

Comment: Yes, it is connected because every point of the first disk can be connected with a path to the point of intersection which can be connected to every point of second disk.

Comment: @leb85 path connected.

Comment: When I said that it was connected I was looked at as though I hadn't considered the question properly, then again maybe I should have specified the topology I was answering in respect to. I had to clarify that 'closed' disks were meant, but after that I assumed we were discussing the euclidean topology because those are some egs of typical closed sets... In any case, thanks for the comments

Comment: the concept of continuity is very important in the proof that path-connectedness implies connectedness.  If you are supposed to pay special attention to the word continuous, then maybe you are supposed to prove the connectedness of the space from its path-connectedness explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose your two disks are $D_1, D_2$ and assume $x\in D_1\cap D_2$. Then let $d_1\in D_1$ and $d_2\in D_2$. We know that since each disk is connected there exists a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow D_1$ so that $f(0)=d_1$ and $f(1)=x$. And similarly there is a continuous function $g:[1,2]\rightarrow D_2$ such that $g(1)=x$ and $g(2)=d_2$. If you glue the functions $f,g$ together what can you say about the continuity of the glued function?

To show connectedness you do something similar. Suppose our space is path connected but not connected. Thus we may write $D=D_1\cup D_2$ as the union of two proper clopen subspaces, say $A_1$ and $A_2$. So in other words $D=A_1\cup A_2$ where $A_1,A_2$ are clopen in the subspace topology. Now take $a_1\in A_1$ and $a_2\in A_2$. Since our space D is path connected there is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow D$ such that $f(0)=a_1$ and $f(1)=a_2$. But note that $f^{pre}(A_1)$ and $f^{pre}(A_2)$ are clopen. What's the contradiction?

Comment: I take it I'm using that $[0,1]$ is connected so the only clopen subsets are itself and $\emptyset$. And then map forward again to get either $A_1$ or $A_2$ is $D$?

Comment: $f^{pre}(A_1)\cup f^{pre}(A_2)=[0,1]$ so what is the contradiction?

Comment: Yes, were using the fact that $[0,1]$ is connected.Remember $f^{pre}(A_1),f^{pre}(A_2)$ are proper clopen subsets of $[0,1]$.Once you determine the contradiction we can conclude our assumption that D is not connected was wrong.